# Nativescript add class to a button on Tap

Tags: nativescript

I am completely new to Nativescript, I am trying to add class Name dynamically to a gridlayout on tap.

I am not using Angular 2.

How to access the grid layout element and add class name to the same.

Answer (score 6):

All that you need to do is search for the desired element in the UI tree for example by accessing the parent of the `Button` or by setting an `id` to the element and using the `.getViewById()` method of the **root** of the Page or the **Page itself**.

Finally in order to set the css class of that View simply set its `className` property, something like this:

```
export function onChangeCssClassButtonTap(args) {
    var button = args.object as Button;
    var parentGridLayout = button.parent as StackLayout;
    parentGridLayout.className = "myGridCssClassName";
}
```

Here are some documentation articles that may be useful to you:

- [Finding View by its id](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#execute-business-logic)
- [Styling in NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling)